# using variable in a function

Tags: maple

my question is that I have a function and a variable and I want the result of function in that point:

```
f := exp(x)*sin(x):
m:=5:
n:=evalf(f, x:=m);
```

but it doesn't work.

in description of f we have:

`description`(exp(__SELECTION(1, 2)) sin(__SELECTION(1, 2)))

but I couldn't figure out what is the problem.
thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Questions primarily about Maple programming rather than mathematics are off-topic in this forum. (More suitable are [stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com) or [www.mapleprimes.com](http://www.mapleprimes.com))

```
f := exp(x)*sin(x):
m:=5:

eval(f, x=m);

         exp(5) sin(5)

evalf(eval(f, x=m));

         -142.3169809
```

Comment: yeah I'm sorry. and thank you.